# Downloading to sd card issues

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, downloading

Recently bought a Vodafone Smart Mini 7 (VFD-300) running Android version 6.0. Even though I have changed my default write disk to sd card, every time I download an app from play store, it downloads it to internal storage. It is supposed to download to the sd card is it not? Is this a normal issue? its a big issue for me basically rendering my phone useless. I have considered rooting etc but would rather not. Am I missing something?

PS I have searched for the 'move to sdcard' option. it seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll say this for a hundred time that SD card cannot be used for apps as is, you can do that with apps like APPS2SD or link2sd (you'll need root for that), or if you have phone running android 6.0+ you can adopt sd card so it becames like internal storage but you can't use it with other phones until you format it.

Here is how to do it (it says for galaxy s7 but it works with all phones the same way):
http://www.modaco.com/news/android/heres-how-to-configure-adoptable-storage-on-your-s7-s7-edge-r1632/